# Get JSON sub element from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I have the following JSON format stored in an NSDictionary. How would I extract `audio_link`?

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "audio_link": "http://www.website.com/Alive.mp3",
      "author": "John",
      "date_created": "2014-02-17 05:12:25"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried

```
NSString * songUrl = [[json objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"url"];
```

but that failed.

Comment: Developers should know how to recognise objects in json. Please have some time to read here will save you time in the future: http://www.json.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have dictionary which contains array of dictionaries. Try that:

```
NSString * songUrl = [[json objectForKey:@"results"][0] objectForKey:@"audio_link"];
```

Comment: I am getting error use of unresolved identifier json

Answer (score 0):

`"results"` is array of dictionaries:

```
{
  "audio_link": "http://www.website.com/Alive.mp3",
  "author": "John",
  "date_created": "2014-02-17 05:12:25"
}
```

and when you call `[[json objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"url"]` it will return you array that contain strings of values for key`"url"`
So, If you dont know how much object will be this array, you should better to use 
`[[[json objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"audio_link"] lastObject]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Mantle](https://github.com/blog/1299-mantle-a-model-framework-for-objective-c). It has solved this in a clean way.

Example:

```
@interface ClassName : MTLModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *audioLink;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *creationDate;
@end

@implementation ClassName
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{
            @"audioLink"    : @"audio_link",
            @"author"       : @"author",
            @"creationDate" : @"date_created"
            };
}
@end


ClassName *item = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[ClassName class] fromJSONDictionary:jsonDictionary["results"][0] error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there may be one, several, or no items in your results array:

```
NSArray* results = json [@"result"];
for (NSDictionary* result in results)
{
    NSString* audioLink = result [@"audioLink"];
    // and so on
}
```

results [0] will throw an exception if there aren't actually any results; the loop "for (NSDictionary* result in results) will work fine if there are no items in results, and even if there is no result array at all.